# Finding empty directories

Tags: bash, unix, directory

I need to find empty directories for a given list of directories.
Some directories have directories inside it.

If inside directories are also empty I can say main directory is empty otherwise it's not empty.

How can I test this?

For example:

```
A>A1(file1),A2 this is not empty beacuse of file1
B>B1(no file) this is empty
C>C1,C2 this is empty
```

Comment: I think Martin's answer is the most appropriate here. The current accepted answer is only an incomplete pseudocode.

Comment: Related: [Checking from shell script if a directory contains files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91368/checking-from-shell-script-if-a-directory-contains-files)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check whether `find <dir> -type f` outputs anything. Here's an example:

```
for dir in A B C; do
    [ -z "`find $dir -type f`" ] && echo "$dir is empty"
done
```

Comment: No, it will not output subdirectories. That's what the `-type f` is for.

Comment: Howerver if there are *empty files*, your solution won't yield the message.

Comment: Yasir: I would think that a directory containing an empty file wound not be empty itself.  Would that not be the correct result?

Comment: @akostadinov: If I create the directories and files as indicated by the OP — `mkdir A B C A/A1 A/A2 B/B1 C/C1 C/C2; touch A/A1/file1` — and run the code in my answer, it reports that B and C are empty, as required by the OP. So you will need to be a little more specific than, "it wont work".

Comment: @MarceloCantos, I said everything needed to reproduce. Having your script work with some example data, does not prove it correct in all corner cases... or course I'm not telling this could be a problem for the OP's use case.

Comment: In the example, B1, C1, and C2 are empty directories for `$dir` values B and C, and it clearly works for them. I'm not saying you're wrong — there possibly is a bug in my code — but it most certainly isn't clear from your comments what the problem is. Perhaps you could supply an example that fails.

Comment: @akostadinov: I just noticed that I didn't address the above response to you, so here's a ping.

Comment: @MarceloCantos, looks like I misread the question. It's very ugly lacking punctuation... sorry for confusion. I think your answer is nice.

Comment: If you are a Bash noob like me, check what -z means [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096670/what-does-z-mean-in-bash).

Comment: the -z question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096670/what-does-z-mean-in-bash

Answer (score 315):

The following will remove all empty directories (those with no children). As it does so depth-first (bottom-up), it will remove directories with only (empty) directories as children. Beware that, in `find`, the order of arguments matters.

```
find testdir -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

Drop `-delete` to see the files and directories matched, however note that because of `-depth`, parent dirs that would *become* empty will not be listed (beware that `-depth` is implied by `-delete` in some `find` implementations). Remove the `-type d` if you would to *also* like to delete empty files.

For example:

```
$ mkdir -p testdir/foo/bar/baz; touch testdir/foo/afile.txt

$ find testdir -printf '%y %p\n' | tee before.txt
d testdir
d testdir/foo
d testdir/foo/bar
d testdir/foo/bar/baz
f testdir/foo/afile.txt

$ find testdir -depth -type d -empty
testdir/foo/bar/baz

$ find testdir -depth -type d -empty -delete

$ find testdir -printf '%y %p\n' | tee after.txt
d testdir
d testdir/foo
f testdir/foo/afile.txt

$ diff -u {before,after}.txt | tail +4
 d testdir
 d testdir/foo
-d testdir/foo/bar
-d testdir/foo/bar/baz
 f testdir/foo/afile.txt
```

Comment: -delete implies -depth (at least for GNU findutils 4.4.2)

Comment: did not know about `-empty`, so convenient!

Comment: However on machine that are not the latest and greatest linux. (EG Solaris), then you have no fancy find features like -empty or -delete.

Comment: @antofthy been a while since I touched Solaris, but you used to have a choice between Sun's own version and the GNU version of various utilities. GNU tools was prefixed with g so perhaps gfind might work

Comment: On MacOS-X, for ***almost*** empty directories, run `find test -name ".DS_Store" -delete` first, then the `-empty delete` command.  Also note, like to `pushd` to the parent directory, so that `find test` becomes `find .`, but the rest of the commands are the same.

Comment: @Martin Can you please add the definition of `-depth` here i.e.  *Cause find to perform a depth-first traversal, i.e., directories are visited in post-order and all entries in a directory will  acted on before the directory itself.* I think it is relevant here.

Comment: You can mix actions as well, such as adding and -ls or -print "find . -depth -type d -empty -ls -delete"

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영,what's the difference between add -depth or not  in this question?

Comment: Be careful in what order you use `-delete` and `-type d` with `-o` unless you want to loose a few hours googling `ext4magic` and loose a few gigs of data still to be backed up.

Answer (score 81):

You can use the following command:

```
find . -type d -empty
```

Comment: -empty only works if the current directory is completely empty, not if the subtree contains no files.

Comment: @soField Tested *find . -type d -empty* with FreeBSD & CentOS. Works fine. What your OS?

Comment: hp-ux so there is no empty parameter

Comment: @soField So, you see, that it's better (for all of us) to post this data at the top of your question...

Comment: find doesn't have -empty on solaris either, but it does have -depth to enforce depth-first traversal so that empty subdirectories can be deleted before the parent directory is checked for emptiness.

Comment: hp-ux curreltny is completly exotic system, usually based on intel itanium cpu. try find GNU tools with its find command.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac Catalina. I have a folder with thousands of empty folders in it, confirmed by `ls`, and if I `cd` to that folder, `find . -type d -empty` returns absolutely nothing. I've seen this work on Mojave, must be Catalina garbage.

Answer (score 28):

```
find directory -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

This is the version that I found most interesting. If executed from inside *directory*, it will delete all empty directories below (a directory is considered empty if it only contains empty directories).

The mindepth option prevents the directory itself from being deleted if it happens to be empty.

Comment: You can follow this up with `rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p directory` to get rid of the parents as well.

Comment: @Pete Peterson My command seems to remove directories that only contain other empty directories (which is what OP also seems to want).  I note that your command will usually leave the user in a directory with a missing i-node even if they accomplish what they want, which may be confusing to them. Maybe I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 24):

`find . -type d -empty`

finds and lists empty directories and sub-directories in the current tree.
E.g. resulting list of empty dirs and subdirs:

```
./2047
./2032
./2049
./2063
./NRCP26LUCcct1/2039
./NRCP26LUCcct1/2054
./NRCP26LUCcct1/2075
./NRCP26LUCcct1/2070
```

No operation is made on the directories. They are simply listed.
This works for me.

Answer (score 18):

### Just find empty dirs

In order to just find empty directories (as specified in the question title), the [mosg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2810883/938111) is correct:

```
find -type d -empty
```

But `-empty` may not be available on very old `find` versions (this is the case of [HP-UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX) for example). If this is your case, see the techniques described in below section *Is a directory empty?*.

### Delete empty dirs

This is a bit tricky: Suppose a directory `MyDir` contains empty directories. After removing these empty directories, `MyDir` will become an empty directory and should also be removed. Therefore I use the command `rmdir` with the option `--parents` (or `-p`) that also removes parent directories when possible:

```
find -type d -empty -exec rmdir -vp --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} +
```

On older `find` version the statement `+` is not yet supported, therefore you may use `;` instead:

```
find -type d -empty -exec rmdir -vp --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} `;`
```

### Is a directory empty?

Most of these answers explain how to check if a directory is empty. Therefore I provide here the three different techniques I know:

1. **`[ $(find your/dir -prune -empty) = your/dir ]`**

   ```
   d=your/dir
   if [ x$(find "$d" -prune -empty) = x"$d" ]
   then
     echo "empty (directory or file)"
   else
     echo "contains files (or does not exist)"
   fi
   ```

   a variation:

   ```
   d=your/dir
   if [ x$(find "$d" -prune -empty -type d) = x"$d" ]
   then
     echo "empty directory"
   else
     echo "contains files (or does not exist or is not a directory)"
   fi
   ```

   **Explanation:**

   - `find -prune` is similar than `find -maxdepth 0` using less characters
   - `find -type d` prints directories only
   - `find -empty` prints the empty directories and files

     ```
     > mkdir -v empty1 empty2 not_empty
     mkdir: created directory 'empty1'
     mkdir: created directory 'empty2'
     mkdir: created directory 'not_empty'
     > touch not_empty/file
     > find empty1 empty2 not_empty -prune -empty
     empty1
     empty2
     ```
2. **`(( ${#files} ))`**

   This trick is 100% `bash` but invokes (spawns) a sub-shell. The idea is from [Bruno De Fraine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91558/938111) and improved by [teambob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141736)'s comment. I advice this one if you use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and if your script does not have to be portable.

   ```
   files=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; echo your/dir/*)
   if (( ${#files} ))
   then 
     echo "contains files"
   else 
     echo "empty (or does not exist or is a file)"
   fi
   ```

   **Note:** no difference between an empty directory and a non-existing one (and even when the provided path is a file).
3. **`[ $(ls -A your/dir) ]`**

   This trick is inspired from [nixCraft's article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-check-if-directory-empty/) posted in 2007. [Andrew Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91394/938111) answered in 2008 and [gr8can8dian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4778234/938111) in 2011.

   ```
   if [ "$(ls -A your/dir)" ]
   then
     echo "contains files"
   else
     echo "empty (or does not exist or is a file)"
   fi
   ```

   or the one-line bashism version:

   ```
   [[ "$(ls -A your/dir)" ]] && echo "contains files" || echo "empty or ..."
   ```

   **Note:** `ls` returns `$?=2` when the directory does not exist. But no difference between a file and an empty directory.

Comment: `rmdir -vp` helped me immensely since I needed to not just delete all empty dirs under a root, but check for empty dirs and parent dirs after deleting a file. In my situation empty dirs are fine as long as they are not in the tree i'm currently removing a file from. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about `rmdir *`? That command will fail on non-empty directories.

Comment: Something I have done at times, for general clean up. Also done things like  `rmdir */*/* */* *`  Though that does not handle 'dot-files' but then in manual situations (cleaning data files) you generally don't expect 'dot-files'.
The recursive methods, however are for more automated general clean up, especially in very large directory structures.

Comment: In one case was more complicated as I needed to remove empty directories where 'empty' included directories that could contain a single 'readme' file. Anything else in the directory and it wasn't 'empty'.  In that example the directory structure involved tens of thousands of sub-directories.

Answer (score 2):

This recursive function would seem to do the trick:

```
# Bash
findempty() {
    find ${1:-.} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir
    do
        if [[ -z "$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type f)" ]] >/dev/null
        then
            findempty "$dir"
            echo "$dir"
        fi
    done
}
```

Given this example directory structure:

```
    .
    |-- dir1/
    |-- dir2/
    |   `-- dirB/
    |-- dir3/
    |   `-- dirC/
    |       `-- file5
    |-- dir4/
    |   |-- dirD/
    |   `-- file4
    `-- dir5/
        `-- dirE/
            `-- dir_V/
```

The result of running that function would be:

```
    ./dir1
    ./dir5/dirE/dir_V
    ./dir5/dirE
    ./dir5
    ./dir2/dirB
    ./dir2
```

which misses `/dir4/dirD`. If you move the recursive call `findempty "$dir"` after the `fi`, the function will include that directory in its results.

Answer (score 1):

The following command returns 1 if a directory is empty (or does not exists) and 0 otherwise (so it is possible to invert the return code with `!` in a shell script):

```sh
find $dir -type d -prune -empty -exec false {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple structure as follows:

`test/
test/test2/
test/test2/test2.2/
test/test3/
test/test3/file`

The `test/test3/file` contains some junk text.

Issuing `find test -empty` returns "`test/test2/test2.2`" as the only empty directory.

Comment: the op asks for test/test2 to be returned also

Comment: Indeed. But I figured he could read the find man page to go further. A script that adjusts depths based on results would work just fine.

Comment: This was the most useful version for mye use, thanks

Answer (score 0):

a simple approach would be,

```
$ [ "$(ls -A /path/to/direcory)" ] && echo "not empty" || echo "its empty"
```

also,

```
if [ "$(ls -A /path/to/direcory)" ]; then
   echo "its not empty"
else 
   echo "empty directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name -type d -ls |awk '($2==0){print $11}'
```