# remove all of a file type from a directory and its children

Tags: bash, unix, shell, scripting

I was under impression that

```
rm -r *.xml
```

would remove all file from parent and child however:

```
*.xml: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The man page of rm says:

```
 -r, -R, --recursive
          remove directories and their contents recursively
```

This means the flag `-r` is expecting a directory.
But `*.xml` is not a directory.

If you want to remove the all .xml files from current directory recursively below is the command:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -type f|xargs rm -f
```

Comment: No need to invoke xargs; use `find -exec`.

Comment: @noa..i know...There are numerous ways to do a similar thing in unix.Its up to the OP  to chose which one to use.I had just given what i regularly use.

Comment: @noa Actually `xargs` is more efficient. `-exec` calls `rm` for every matching file, whereas `xargs` does it in batches. This can make a big difference when there are lots of files.

Comment: Interesting. That makes sense.

Comment: `xargs` can be more efficient for *expensive* operations if you use the `-P` options to run tasks in parallel, but probably won't make much difference in this case. However, I agree with @Rahul that it's up to users what they prefer, and one can argue that the syntax for `find...|xargs...` is easier to remember than `find .. -exec ... {} \;`. (hence +1)

Answer (score 30):

I'm assuming you want to remove all `*.xml` files recursively (within current and all sub directories). To do that, use [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec rm {} \;
```

---

On a side note, recursive deletion scares me. On my saner days, I tend to precede that step with:

```
find . -name "*.xml"
```

(without the `-exec` bit) just to see what might get deleted before taking the leap. I advice you do the same. Your files will thank you.

Comment: Yup want to do it for a few different types. However your script does not seem to be working within the Bash.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `{}` - the original version was fine - the OP probably just mis-typed it.

Comment: Yeah this worked for me, because I had a bunch of file paths with spaces

Comment: helpful for the side note of caution before deletion.

Answer (score 10):

Reading [this answer on finding empty directories unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811135/709769), I just learned about the -delete action:

```
-delete
          Delete  files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed, an error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit status will be nonzero (when it even‐
          tually exits).  Use of -delete automatically turns on the -depth option.

          Warnings: Don't forget that the find command line is evaluated as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to delete everything below the start‐
          ing  points  you  specified.   When  testing a find command line that you later intend to use with -delete, you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid
          later surprises.  Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

*Source: man find*

That means, you can also delete all xml-files recursively like this:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -type f -delete
```

Comment: This should be the top voted answer, much easier than piping to xargs

Comment: @skd nothing is more easier than `rm -rf */*.xml` for me, so I'd pick my own answer, but it's not allowed :D

Answer (score 4):

more beautiful way, although this one is less supported in unix systems:

```
rm -rf */*.xml
```

this will remove xml files from all sub-directories of you current directory.

Comment: will this work for directory trees that are deeper than just 2 levels?

Answer (score 2):

ZSH recursive globbing to the rescue!

Invoke zsh:
`zsh`

Be sure you're in the dir you intend to be in:
`cd wherever`

List first:
`ls **/*.xml`

Remove:
`rm **/*.xml`

I'll resist the strong temptation to bash on `bash`, and just point to the relevant zsh docs on the topic [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing).

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to do is

> rm -f *.xml

This will remove all .xml files from current directory.

Comment: but not from nested directories, and that what is asked in the topic.