# Grunt - delete all files and files in sub-directories with specific file extension

Tags: gruntjs

I need to delete all files with a specific file extension in a directory and all of its sub-directories using Grunt.js and I guess I probably need a module to do so? I've looked at clean but that seems to be for deleting whole directories rather than specific files.

My directory looks like:

- build/img/
- build/img/ico
- build/img/logos

and the file extension I want to delete is:

Any file with the extension of `.png~`, `.gif~` or `.jpg~`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can configure the `grunt-contrib-clean` task to remove those files like this:

```
clean : {
    yourTarget : {
        src : [ "build/img/**/*.png~", 
                "build/img/**/*.gif~", 
                "build/img/**/*.jpg~"
        ]
    }
}
```

See [this section](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) of the docs for an explanation of `**`, `*`, and other globbing patterns.

Comment: In one line : `src : [ "build/img/**/*.{png,gif,jpg}~"]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Easy, knee-jerk, response is to use [Exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) + a one line shell script like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096528/remove-all-of-a-file-type-from-a-directory-and-its-children):

`find . -name "*.png" -type f|xargs rm -f`

Comment: Exec is nice, will come in handy in the future.

Comment: That won't work if files have quotes or other "odd" characters in. You can use the `-delete` primitive with `find`, though:

`find . -name '*.png' -type f -delete`