# How to remove file that matches regex in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, regex, gruntjs

How to write a task that will delete files in specific folder if they match regular expression?

Suppose we have folder 'somedir' and several files in it:

```
somedir/filename.txt
somedir/filename-good-0.0.1.txt
somedir/filename-0.0.2.txt
```

I want a task that will delete all files in this folder that match this pattern:

```
/.+-\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.txt/
```

I.e. "filename-good-0.0.1.txt" and "filename-0.0.2.txt"

Is it possible?

**Solution:**
Here is Grunt config for this:

```
clean: {
  mytask: {
    src: [ 'somedir/*.txt' ],
    filter: function(filepath) {
      var regex = /.+-\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.txt/g;
      return regex.test(filepath);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to [Ludovic V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5074146/ludovic-v) for the hint.

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223237/grunt-delete-all-files-and-files-in-sub-directories-with-specific-file-extensi

Comment: The issue described there solved using globbs matching. I have a more complicated case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom filter function as describe here: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function and the `match` function String in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you! This is that I missed in Grunt documentation. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`grunt-contrib-clean`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean) to remove files/folders according to rules you give.

Comment: But how to use pure regular expressions(not blobbs, etc) in grunt-contrib-clean configuration? Could you please provide an accurate solution?