# Remove all ignored files from the git history, but not from local filesystem

Tags: git

There were a few questions about removing certain files from git history (i.e., [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)). However, I can't find a way to remove all the .gitignore'd files from history. The problem is I had a personal local repository and didn't care much about the ignored files, but now I need to share it and it would take forever to upload it to the server because of plenty irrelevant *.csv, *.zip and other files. They are spread between quite a few directories and it would be hard to perform this task one-by-one.

So, is it possible to perform a `git rm --cached` on all files with certain extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the sort of task for which [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) was designed. You could do something like this:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm *.csv *.zip' HEAD
```

It would be best to perform this operation in another clone of your repository, if you want to keep those files untracked in your local working directory.

Comment: Hmm... it throws "cannot remove `*.csv': No such file or directory"

Comment: I guess git isn't running the command through the shell, so shell expansion isn't happening. Try `--tree-filter 'sh -c "rm *.csv *.zip"'`

Comment: Tried it, same thing.

Comment: I just noticed you said they are "spread between quite a few directories" so I guess they're not in the repository root. So you'll have to adjust your command as necessary to delete the files you want. I don't know your directory structure so I can't say exactly what you will need to do.

Comment: So, I need to do something like `rm dir1/dir2/*.zip` or there is a better way to cover all the files?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096528/remove-all-of-a-file-type-from-a-directory-and-its-children for an example of how to do that.

Comment: The "tree filter" *is* run through the shell (`eval`-ed), the problem is that `*.csv` is not matching anything.  Also note that filter-branch is kind of a pain to use.  Someone wrote [BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) as an alternative.