# Finding all empty directories (folders) in Windows

Tags: windows, directory, is-empty

How to find all empty directories in Windows? For Unix there exists [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810838/finding-empty-directories-unix). So there is an out of the box solution. What is the best solution using Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several solutions so far:

1. Use [Powershell to find empty directories](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730953.aspx)
2. Install Cygwin or [Gnu Findtools](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) and follow the [unix approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810838/finding-empty-directories-unix)
3. Use Python or some other script language, e.g. Perl

This Powershell snippet below will search through C:\whatever and return the empty subdirectories

```
$a = Get-ChildItem C:\whatever -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
$a | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | Select-Object FullName
```

WARNING: The above will ALSO return all directories that contain subdirectories (but no files)!

This python code below will list all empty subdirectories

```
import os;
folder = r"C:\whatever";

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    if (dirs == files): print path
```

Comment: I would say Powershell approach should be the one to be used by the OP. Do you imagine using a Unix abstraction layer/emulator if there's a Windows-based solution? ;)

Comment: Yes, I am working on both windows and unix and thus prefer solutions that work with both. Actually in the case where this issue came up I preferred the python solution. I just added the powershell way for completeness. I will sort it up though.

Answer (score 1):

The Powershell script in the accepted answer does not actually find truly empty folders (directories).  It considers a folder with subfolders to be empty.  Much of the blame lies on Microsoft, who wrote that script.  Apparently, Microsoft considers a folder that contains subfolders to be empty.  *That explains a lot of things.*

Here is a 1-line Powershell script that will actually return all empty folders.  I define an empty folder to be a folder that is actually, um, empty.

```
(gci C:\Example -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count + $_.GetDirectories().Count -eq 0} | select FullName
```

In the above example, replace `C:\Example` with any path you would like to check.  To check an entire drive, simple specify the root (e.g. `C:\` for drive `C`).

Answer (score 0):

One can also call Win32 functions from Powershell, `PathIsDirectoryEmptyW` will return true if Directory is empty.

```
$MethodDefinition = @’

[DllImport(“Shlwapi.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern bool PathIsDirectoryEmptyW(string lpExistingDirName);

‘@

$Shlwapi = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name ‘Shlwapi’ -Namespace ‘Win32’ -PassThru


$a = Get-ChildItem C:\whatever -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
$a | Where-Object {$Shlwapi::PathIsDirectoryEmptyW("$($_.FullName)")} | Select-Object FullName
```