# How to specify "if directory not empty " in a ash shell script?

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell script. My script goes into a directory, but I want that it only proceeds and executes the next commands if the directory contains any data (the directory is not empty). Otherwise it shouldn't goes any further. How can I specify such a condition in my shell script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a directory contains files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91368/checking-if-a-directory-contains-files)

Answer (score 3):

use test with "$(ls -A $DIR)" like:

```
if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
     echo "directory is not empty"
else
    echo "directory is Empty"
fi
```

Comment: +1  Note that `-A` is not POSIX, but a BSD-introduced extension also supported under GNU.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ `find dir -type f | wc -l` = "0" ]
then
  echo no files
else
  echo files
fi
```

This'll check `dir` and subdirectories. `find dir -maxdepth 1 -type f` will check only `dir`

If you want to count subdirectories as well as files:

```
find dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: Rather than piping to wc -l, it is cleaner to use grep: if find dir -type f | grep -q .; then ...; fi

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
     echo "Take action $DIR is not Empty"
else
    echo "$DIR is Empty"
fi
```