# How to test if a directory is empty with find

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I am trying to write an if statement in a unix shell script that returns true if it's empty, and false if it's not.

This type of thing...

```
if directory foo is empty then
echo empty
else
echo not empty
fi
```

How do I do this?  I'm told find is a good palce to start

Answer (score 7):

Simple - use the -empty flag. Quoting the find man page:

> ```
>  -empty  True if the current file or directory is empty.
> ```

So something like:

```
find . -type d -empty
```

Will list all the empty directories.

Answer (score 3):

Three best answers:

1. The first one is based on `find` as OP requested ;
2. The second is based on `ls` ;
3. The third one is 100% `bash` but it invokes (spawns) a sub-shell.

### 1. `[ $(find your/dir -prune -empty) = your/dir ]`

```
dn=your/dir
if [ x$(find "$dn" -prune -empty) = x"$dn" ]; then
  echo empty
else
  echo not empty
fi
```

**test:**

```
> mkdir -v empty1 empty2 not_empty
mkdir: created directory 'empty1'
mkdir: created directory 'empty2'
mkdir: created directory 'not_empty'
> touch not_empty/file
> find empty1 empty2 not_empty -prune -empty
empty1
empty2
```

`find` has printed the two empty directories only (`empty1` and `empty2`).

This answer looks like the [`-maxdepth 0 -empty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6845692/938111) from [Ariel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664364). But this answer is a bit shorter ;)

### 2. `[ $(ls -A your/directory) ]`

```
if [ "$(ls -A your/dir)" ]; then
  echo not empty
else
  echo empty
fi
```

or

```
[ "$(ls -A your/dir)" ] && echo not empty || echo empty
```

Similar to [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6845624/938111) and [gpojd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6845597/938111) answers. But here we do not require to pipe to `wc`. See also [Bash Shell Check Whether a Directory is Empty or Not](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-check-if-directory-empty/) by [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/about-us) (2007).

### 3. `(( ${#files} ))`

```
files=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; echo your/dir/*)
if (( ${#files} )); then 
  echo not empty
else 
  echo empty or does not exist
fi
```

Caution: as written in this above example, there is no difference between an empty directory and a non-existing one.

This last answer has been inspired from the [Bruno De Fraine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91558/938111) and the excellent comments from [teambob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141736).

Answer (score 2):

There must be an easier way, but you can test for an empty/nonempty directory with `ls -1A` piped to `wc -l`

```
DIRCOUNT=$(ls -1A /path/to/dir |wc -l)
if [ $DIRCOUNT -eq 0 ]; then
  # it's empty
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find directoryname -maxdepth 0 -empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use find? In bash, `ls -a` will return two files (`.` and `..`) for an empty directory and should have more than that for non-empty ones.

```
if [ $(ls -a | wc -l) -eq 2 ]; then echo "empty"; else echo "not empty"; fi
```

Comment: I checked that it has two values to account for the `.` and `..`. The -l flag is not necessary when piped to wc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ `find foo | wc -l` -eq 1 ]
then
    echo Empty
else
    echo Not empty
fi
```

`foo` is the directory name here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below

```
dircnt.sh:
-----------
#!/bin/sh

if [ `ls $1 2> /dev/null | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

Usage

```
andreas@earl ~
$ mkdir asal

andreas@earl ~
$ sh dircnt.sh asal
false

andreas@earl ~
$ touch asal/1

andreas@earl ~
$ sh dircnt.sh asal
true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using ls because I have some very large directories and I hate wasting the resources to fill a pipe with all that stuff.

I don't like filling a $files variable with all that stuff either.

So while all of @libre's answers are interesting, I find them all unreadable, and prefer to make a function of my favorite, the 'find' solution:

```
function isEmptyDir {
  [ -d $1 -a -n "$( find $1 -prune -empty 2>/dev/null )" ]
}
```

So that I can write code that I can read a year from now without asking "what was I thinking"?

```
if isEmptyDir some/directory
then
  echo "some/directory is empty"
else
  echo "some/directory does not exist, is not a directory, or is empty
fi
```

or I can use additional code to tease apart the negative results, but that code
should be pretty obvious.  In any case, I'll know right away what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

NO script, no fork/exec (echo is a builtin)...

```
[ "$(cd $dir;echo *)" = "*" ] && echo empty || echo non-empty
```