# Test if file exist, bash script

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if a directory contains files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91368/checking-if-a-directory-contains-files)

I want to see if a directory is empty, so I am using `[` as follows:

```
[ -f "./ini/*"]
```

And the return value is always 1, even though the directory is not empty.
Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91368/checking-if-a-directory-contains-files

Comment: Can't work because there's no globbing performed in double quoted strings. You test for the existence of a file named `*` in the ini directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo "*"   #With quotes
```

vs.

```
$ echo *    #No quotes
```

See the difference? When you put quotes around a string, the shell can't *glob* to replace the asterisk with the matching files.

There are multitude of ways to get what you want. Simplest is to use the `ls` command without the test command. The `if` statement takes the output results of the ***command*** you give it. The `[...]` simply are an alias to the `test` command. These two statements are equivalent:

```
$ if test -f foo.txt

$ if [ -f foo.txt ]
```

Basically, all the test command does is return a `0` if the test is true or a non-zero if the test is false. All the `if` command does is execute the `if` statement if the command it's given returns a `0` exit code. The reason I'm going all through this is to say let's forget the test and simply use the `ls` command.

Assume that you have a file `foo.txt`, but no file `bar.txt`. Try the following:

```
$ ls foo.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?
0
$ ls bar.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?
2
```

The `> /dev/null 2>&1` is used to inhibit all output. Notice that the exit code of the `ls` command when a file exists is `0` while the exit code of the `ls` command when the file doesn't exist isn't `0`. (It's `2` in this case). Now, let's use that instead of the test command:

```
if ls ./ini/* > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "There are files in that directory!"
else
    echo "There are no files in that directory"
fi
```

Notice I don't even bother with the test command (which can be the word `test` or the `[..]`).

Hope this makes sense to you. It's sometimes difficult for people to realize that in BASH shell, the `if` command and the `[...]` are two separate commands, and all `if` is doing is running the command it's given and then acting depending upon the exit code of the command it runs.

Comment: Being semantically pedantic, `[` is a command but `if` is not.  Rather, `if` is a keyword of the shell.

Answer (score 3):

Beware of filenames starting with '.', normal globbing or using `ls` (*shudder*) will not detect those  There are several ways to do this, the simplest I can come up with is:

```
/home/user1> mkdir ini
/home/user1> cd ini
/home/user1/ini> touch .fred jim tom dick harry
/home/user1/ini> cd ..
/home/user1> declare -a names
/home/user1> names=(./ini/* ./ini/.*)
/home/user1> number_of_files=$(( ${#names[@]} -2 ))
/home/user1> echo $number_of_files
5
```

The `-2` is required to remove `.` and `..` from the list.

Comment: also consider `nullglob` and `dotglob` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if find ./ini/ -maxdepth 0 -empty | read;
then
echo "Not Empty"
else
echo "Empty"
fi
```

Comment: what is `| read` doing there ? this is not the way to hide output..

Comment: The read is both to discard the output and make the expression evaluate to true only when something is read (i.e. /some/dir/ is found empty by find).

Comment: if `find` doesn't find any files it will return `1`. if you want to hide the output use `&>/dev/null` for Bash, and `1>/dev/null 2>&1` for sh.

Comment: Got rid of the `test` which is good. However, a simple `ls ./ini/* > /dev/null 2>&1` would be faster and easier.

Answer (score 0):

If the output of the command below is `0` then no files in directory (Directory empty) else it has files!

```
$find "/path/to/check" -type f -exec echo {} \;|wc -l
```

so for you -

```
exist=`find "./ini" -type f -exec echo {} \;|wc -l`
if [ $exist -gt 0 ]
then
   echo "Directory has files"
else
   echo "Directory is empty"
fi
```

Or

```
if [ `find "./ini" -type f -exec echo {} \;|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
   echo "Directory has files"
else
   echo "Directory is empty"
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

This works for me

```
[ "$(ls -A /path/to/directory)" ]
```

in your case it would be

```
[ "$(ls -A ./ini/)" ]
```

you can test it using

```
[ "$(ls -A /tmp)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs . Friends don't let friends parse the output of `ls`.