# Directory check and mv command

Tags: bash, unix, move

I want to check if a directory is not empty then move it to another directory else move on to the next directory.

I know it possible but getting my "if's" and "then's" mixed up. This is what I have done so far:

```
    if [ "$(ls -A /Volumes/Editorial\ Data/Photography/Digital\ Photographer/Content\ King\ DP)" ]; then
       echo "Not Empty"
    else
       echo "Empty"
    fi
    mv -n /Volumes/Editorial\ Data/Photography/Digital\ Photographer/Content\ King\ DP/* /Volumes/SAN\ CK1/Content\ King/2015/Magazines/Digital\ Photographer
```

The purpose of this script is to in sequence check 20+ separate directories for contents, each has a corresponding directory on another disk and if it finds anything in the source directory it moves it to the destination directory.

Once I get this one right I need to string 20 or more directories to check and move in a single script.

Comment: Please don't use the comments to add more detail to your question; instead, [edit] it.

Comment: @TomFenech sorry, i did realise my mistake and move it, i'm still new to this forum and getting used to its ways/functions. thanks as always

Comment: @TomFenech folder changed to directory

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of known directories, I would suggest an approach like this:

```
for dir in path/one path/two path/three; do
    contents=( "$dir"/* )
    if [[ ${#contents[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
        mv "${contents[@]}" /destination/dir
    fi
done
```

A glob is used to fill an array with every path inside the directory. If the length of the array is greater than zero, all the files are moved to the destination.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i should heave said each folder i check has a corresponding folder that the contents needs to be moved to as a posed one folder to receive all.

Comment: what is the mapping between the input directory and output? Are the names related or something? You should edit your question to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Using the beautiful answer [by mweerden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91639/1983854) in [Checking from shell script if a directory contains files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/91368/1983854), you can say:

```
if [ -n "$(find aaa/ -maxdepth 0 -empty)" ]; then
   mv -n /Folder/Source/* /Folder/Destination
fi
```

Or even shorter:

```
[ -n "$(find aaa/ -maxdepth 0 -empty)" ] && mv -n /Folder/Source/* /Folder/Destination
```

`[ -n "$variable" ]` checks if the length of `$variable` is nonzero.

#### Explanation

`find ... -empty` just outputs the name of the given directory if it does not contain anything.

```
$ mkdir aaa/
$ find aaa/ -maxdepth 0 -empty
aaa/
```

Now it won't print anything:

```
$ touch aaa/bbb
$ find aaa/ -maxdepth 0 -empty
$
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this relies on GNU find for `-maxdepth`.

Comment: Good point, @TomFenech . Updating to show that it can be done differently... in fact no, I cannot do it because it would become weird. I thought about doing `find dir/ -type f` but we may want to also check dirs within that directory, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and multiple solutions, do i replace aaa with the path to the folder to be check? and do i just repeat the command  for all subsequent folders?

Comment: @ImagineAdmin since you are adding more info about your question in comments here and in the other answer, better update your question to show more context.

Answer (score 0):

I see to ways to do this:

```
if [[ ! -z $(find $dir -type f -type d) ]]
then
    echo "Directory Not Empty. Move the files."
fi
```

This tests to see if any files are returned by the `find` command. Note I have to test the output to see if there are no files. The `find` will return an exit code of 0 even if nothing is found as long as the command is good.

and

```
if ! ls $dir/* > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "Directory Not Empty. Move the files."
fi
```

Note in the second one, I don't use `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]` tests. If there is nothing under `$dir`, the `ls $dir/*` will return a non-zero status, and my `if` statement will pick that up.

This should be much more efficient. I'm not shelling out to a new command, and `ls` should be faster than `find` if the purpose is to see if there are any entries at all under the directory. It'd be nice if I could use `$dir/*` directly without bothering with a command... I think you might be able to do something with `shopt -s failglob` which will exit in case of a glob expansion failure. Then, you might be able to use that output to test if you have any files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestion, with my very limited programming skills i have tried all the various permutations without success. I found that permission had a part to play in it so added the chown line but had to run that as root so added the line into the sudoers file so it sets the correct permission before it checks the folder for contents.

So far i have tried:

```
sudo chown -R admin /Volumes/Editorial\ Data/Photography/Digital\ Photographer/Content\ King\ DP if ! ls $(find /Volumes/Editorial\     Data/Photography/Digital\ Photographer/Content\ King\ DP/* > /dev/null 2>&1     then echo "Directory Not Empty. Move the files." mv -n /Volumes/Editorial\     Data/Photography/Digital\ Photographer/Content\ King\ DP/* /Volumes/SAN\     CK1/Content\ King/2015/Magazines/Digital\ Photographer fi
```

as well as:

```
sudo chown -R admin /Volumes/Editorial\ Data/Photography/Digital\ Photographer/Content\ King\ DP if [ -n "$(find /Volumes/Editorial\ Data/Photography/Digital\ Photographer/Content\ King\ DP/ -maxdepth 1 -empty)" ]; then mv -n /Volumes/Editorial\ Data/Photography/Digital\ Photographer/Content\ King\ DP/* /Volumes/SAN\ CK1/Content\ King/2015/Magazines/Digital\ Photographer fi
```

but can't get it to work, i'll sure people are pulling their hair out looking at my shoddy coding but i know i'm close as the move command part works fine its just the after checking the folder its not then moving anything it finds.