# how to efficiently find if a linux directory including sudirectories has at least 1 file

Tags: linux, bash

In my project various jobs are created as files in directories inside subdirectories. 
But usually the case is I find that the jobs are mostly in some dirs and not in the most others

currently I use

```
find $DIR -type f | head -n 1
```

to know if the directory has atleast 1 file , but this is a waste

how to efficiently  find if a linux directory including sudirectories  has at least 1 file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking from shell script if a directory contains files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91368/checking-from-shell-script-if-a-directory-contains-files)

Comment: Another twist `[ "$(find . -type f -printf "." | grep -c '.')" -eq 1 ]` which tries to be efficient by only outputting a single `'.'` per file. For a count of the files `find . -type f -printf "." | wc -c`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already efficient, but perhaps the reason is not obvious.  When you pipe the output of `find` to `head -n 1` you probably assume that `find` lists all the files and then `head` discards everything after the first one.  But that's not quite what `head` does.

When `find` lists the first file, `head` will print it, but when `find` lists the second file, `head` will terminate itself, which sends `SIGPIPE` to `find` because the pipe between them is closed.  Then `find` will stop running, because the default signal handler for `SIGPIPE` terminates the program which receives it.

So the cost of your pipelined commands is only the cost of finding two files, not the cost of finding all files.  For most obvious use cases this should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find -type f -printf '%h\n' | uniq
```

The `find` part finds all files, but prints only the directory.  The `uniq` part eliminates duplicates.

Pitfall: It doesn't work (like your example) for files containing a NEWLINE in the directory path.

Answer (score 0):

This command finds the first subdiretory containing at least one file and then stop:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'c=$(find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -print -quit);test "x$c" != x' \; -print -quit
```

The first `find` iterates through all subdirectories and second `find` finds the first file and then stop.