# Check if directory has any files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to check if a directory has any files inside it, recursively, but don't care if there is empty sub directories.

I can't use the classic

```
[ "$(ls -A /E/Nuvem/Músicas)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
```

because it considers sub directories too.

I've tried check whole folder size, but each empty folder has 4kb. And I couldn't do anything with `find`

EDIT: I'm uploading files to the AWS S3 cloud and I don't need to send empty folders, I just keep them to help organize new files.

Comment: Why not `find`?

Comment: How to use find for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking from shell script if a directory contains files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91368/checking-from-shell-script-if-a-directory-contains-files)

Comment: `[ -n "$(find /tmp/folder -prune -empty)" ] && echo 'empty' || echo 'not empty'`

Comment: @0stone0 This question and answers seems not to ignore sub directories. I've tryed your solution, but it shows 'not empty' with a folder with an empty subfolder, where I expect 'empty'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this would work for you:

```
[ "$(find /E/Nuvem/Músicas -maxdepth 1 -type f)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
```

EDIT: If you would like to check subfolders for files, just ignore the `-maxdepth 1` option:

```
[ "$(find /E/Nuvem/Músicas -type f)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
```

Comment: If the folder has a subfolder with a file inside it, the result should be "Not Empty" and this test shows "Empty"... But removing `-maxdepth 1` seems to work.