# Check if folder is empty using bash, folder may have spaces

Tags: bash

I have a loop that gets all the subdirectories of a folder.

If the subdirectory is empty I want to do something. However the subdirectory may have a space in the name, and the code I found to check if the directory works errors, I tried escaping it programmatically, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
for folder in "$SEARCH_FOLDER"/*/*; do
 escapedFolder=$(printf %q "$folder")
  if [ -z "$(ls -A $escapedFolder)" ]; then
    echo "$folder is empty"
  else
    echo "$folder is not empty"
  fi
done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `printf %q` is only needed when you're evaluating data as code with something like `eval` or `ssh somehost "...$variable..."` or so forth. You don't need it in any other circumstance, certainly not here. Quote your expansions: `ls -A "$folder"` (no need to ever create `escapedFolder` at all) -- and make a habit of running your code through https://shellcheck.net/

Comment: (similarly, `echo $escapedFolder` is itself inherently buggy; see [I just assigned a variable but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else))

Comment: BTW, if you have bash 5.0 or later, `escapedFolder=${folder@Q}` is a much more efficient way to generate an escaped version of a variable, if you _did_ have a genuine need for one.

Comment: To jump back to the very first comment, and maybe provide some helpful explanation: The reason `ls -A $escapedFolder` doesn't work the way you expect is that your string is **not** treated as code, even when expanded unquoted. Unquoted expansions only go through a small subset of the parsing process -- specifically, word-splitting on characters in IFS, and glob-matching against filesystem contents. This is a Good Thing; it would be impossible to write secure software in bash if data were silently parsed as code.

Comment: But if I quote `ls -A "$folder"` I run into issues because of the outside quotes in `"$(ls -A $folder)"`.  I tried `"$(ls -A \"$folder\")"` but that didnt work either.

Comment: `$( )` starts a new quoting context. Quotes outside it and quotes inside it don't cancel each other out or interact in any other way. You might be thinking of _backticks_ -- those required the escaping you're referring to -- but that's a major part of why `$( )` was introduced to replace them.

Comment: That is to say, `[ -z "$(ls -A "$folder")" ]` is perfectly valid code. I wouldn't call it _good_ code, but it's legal. If some editor or syntax highlighting tool is telling you it's wrong, that tool is broken.

Comment: (_good_ code wouldn't use `ls` to check if a directory is empty; think about `contents=( "$folder"/* ); if [[ -e ${contents[0]} || -L ${contents[0]} ]]; then echo "$folder is not empty"; else echo "$folder is empty"; fi` instead -- granted, that requires a little adjustment, f/e prefixing with `unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -s dotglob`, if you want hidden files to be considered).

Comment: See [BashFAQ/004 (How can I check whether a directory is empty or not? ...)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) and [Checking from shell script if a directory contains files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/91368/4154375).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! The not needing to escape the quotes was the key part I was missing (I dont often write bash, im still fairly new at it). I also appreciate the additional information on how I could do it better :)